# JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 121 column 2 (char 4371)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am loading a json file of tweets using this code

```
with open('tweet.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data[0]['text'])
```

Error:
   JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 121 column 2 (char 4371)

My file looks like this:
[image]

Link to the file [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13YexzRf8LSm6kQhGzmnrt6MIZ6DissH2)

Comment: your json is not valid replace `} {` with a `,`

Comment: Take the JSON you are trying to parse and feed it into https://jsonlint.com/. It will test it’s validity.